# Chrome Extension Error: Refused to execute inline event handler

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is no inline script, but it still returns an error.

**new.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Something</title>
        </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="increment()">Click Me!</button>
        <p id = "lal">2</p>
        <script src = "popup.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**popup.js**

```
var num = 1;
function increment(){
    document.getElementById("lal").innerHTML = num * 2;
    num = num * 2;
}
```

Comment: `<button onclick="increment()">` is an inline event handler.

Comment: Oh maybe it is ill go check